# I want to count people according to their cities and put them in three categories as in which city there are more than 5 people

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have two columns. `1-coloumn (city)` `2-(names of people)`
there are many cities as Mumbai, Madras, Noida,Patna
and many people belongs to this cities.

```
cities  people
mumbai  ranjeet
mumbai  rath
mumbai  raman
delhi   jeten
delhi   gag
ranchi  hhh
ranchi  hjhilj
ranchi  jklkjjkl
ranchi  sa
ranchi  DASD
ranchi  DAS
agra    CACSS
agra    As
agra    DASD
agra    AS
agra    awd
bhubaneswar DS
bhubaneswar DFSA
bhubaneswar asd
bhubaneswar SD
bhubaneswar d
bhubaneswar As
```

I want to query in three categories as `1,2-5,>5` people i.e count people for specific cities and put them to the above categories e.g in Mumbai lies three peoples which comes in 2-5 categories

Comment: can you show us what you already done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, this query should help you:

```
SELECT cities,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN '1'
            WHEN COUNT(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 5 THEN '2-5'
            WHEN COUNT(*) > 5 THEN '5'
        END category,
       LISTAGG(people, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY people) AS names  
  FROM your_table
 GROUP 
    BY cities
```

Comment: What you have done is correct buti also want to know the poples names sidewise as city people(count) names..  thanks

Comment: What DBMS you're using? And can you please provide a sample of your expected result. It makes it easier to understand what you want.

Comment: @ DirkNM  SELECT cities,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(names) = 1 THEN '1 person'
            WHEN COUNT(names) BETWEEN 2 AND 5 THEN '2-5 persons'
            WHEN COUNT(names) > 5 THEN 'more than 5 persons'
        END category
  FROM citypeopleMapping
 GROUP BY cities order by 1 desc